# How to find key from value in rest assured java?

Tags: java, rest, post, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

I am using rest assured java and i am using post request in order to get the response. From my code i am able to get the response and i am seeing that in response i am seeing that value which i want to store is present in the keyset.
Here is the example:

```
{
    "status_code": 200,
    "status_message": "OK",
    "response": {
        "applications": {
            "345": "A",
            "125": "B",
            "458": "C",
            "434": "D",
            "512": "E",
            "645": "F"
        }
    }
}
```

In the above example i am using Json path to parse through the expression and i want to use Value "A" extract the key("345") from it.

```
JsonPath js = new JsonPath(res);
String Key  = js.get("response.applications.A");
```

when i am using above code it throws an error but when i run the below code.

```
JsonPath js = new JsonPath(res);
String Key  = js.get("response.applications.345");
```

I get the output as A.
I know what is [A,b,c,d,e,f] but i don't know what is Key for [A,b,c,d,e,f]

Is there any way where i can store the value and prints the key for that value in rest assured or any other way in Java?????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `JsonPath`, you can get the keys by calling `getMap`. Here is an example of how you would go about doing this:

```
String jsonString = "{\"status_code\": 200,\"status_message\": \"OK\",\"response\":{\"applications\":{\"345\": \"A\",\"125\": \"B\",\"458\": \"C\",\"434\": \"D\",\"512\": \"E\",\"645\": \"F\"}}}";
JsonPath jsonPath = new JsonPath(jsonString);
Map<String, String> applicationsMap = jsonPath.getMap("response.applications");
Set<String> applicationKeys = applicationsMap.keySet();
for(String key:applicationKeys){
    System.out.println("Key value: " + key + ", Element value: " + applicationsMap.get(key));
}
```

Hope this helps!